# Java API creating table, but CRUD operations not working with MySQL DB

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

I have created an API in Java, using Springboot and Maven.

I did all of this following a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RfHBm5yRxuw&list=PLcs1FElCmEu121gqGwlQt47d0SqNkzSTK&index=2) and it's all working, it create a table and I see it from MySQL on terminal, but when I try doing some CRUD operations or access it on "localhost:8080/prodotti", it's not working and giving me error "404".

Here are some code snippets:

**Controller:**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/prodotti")
public class ControllerProdotti {

ServizioProdotti servizioProdotti;

public ControllerProdotti(ServizioProdotti servizioProdotti) {
    this.servizioProdotti = servizioProdotti;
}

// Legge prodotto con id specifico
@GetMapping("/{id}")
public Prodotti getDettagliProdotti(@PathVariable("id") Integer idProdotti) {
    return servizioProdotti.getProdotti(idProdotti);
}

// Legge tutti i prodotti
@GetMapping("/")
public java.util.List<Prodotti> getAllProdotti() {
    return servizioProdotti.getAllProdotti();
}

@PostMapping("/")
public String createDettagliProdotti(@RequestBody Prodotti prodotti) {

    servizioProdotti.creaProdotto(prodotti);

    return "Prodotto creato con successo!";
}

@PutMapping("/")
public String updateDettagliProdotti(@RequestBody Prodotti prodotti) {
    
    servizioProdotti.aggiornaProdotto(prodotti);

    return "Prodotto aggiornato con successo!";
}

@DeleteMapping("{id}")
public String deleteDettagliProdotti(@PathVariable("id") Integer idProdotti) {
    
    servizioProdotti.cancellaProdotto(idProdotti);

    return "Prodotto cancellato con successo!";
}
```

**Repository:**

```
public interface repositoryProdotti extends 
JpaRepository<Prodotti, Integer> {}
```

**Service:**

```
public interface ServizioProdotti {
    public String creaProdotto(Prodotti prodotti);
    public String aggiornaProdotto(Prodotti prodotti);
    public String cancellaProdotto(Integer idProdotti);
    public Prodotti getProdotti(Integer idProdotti);
    public List<Prodotti> getAllProdotti();
}
```

**Implementation:**

```
@Service
public class ImplementazioneProdotti implements ServizioProdotti{
    repositoryProdotti RepositoryProdotti;
    public ImplementazioneProdotti(repositoryProdotti RepositoryProdotti) {
        this.RepositoryProdotti = RepositoryProdotti;
    }
    @Override
    public String creaProdotto(Prodotti prodotti) {

        // Altre operazioni/logica qui

        RepositoryProdotti.save(prodotti);

        return "Creato con successo!";
    }
    @Override
    public String aggiornaProdotto(Prodotti prodotti) {
        RepositoryProdotti.save(prodotti);
        return "Aggiornato con successo!";
    }

    @Override
    public String cancellaProdotto(Integer idProdotti) {
        RepositoryProdotti.deleteById(idProdotti);
        return "Cancellato con successo!";
    }

    @Override
    public Prodotti getProdotti(Integer idProdotti) {
        return RepositoryProdotti.findById(idProdotti).get();
    }

    @Override
    public List<Prodotti> getAllProdotti() {
        return RepositoryProdotti.findAll();
    }  
}
```

**application.properties**

```
# ===============================
# = DATA SOURCE
# ===============================

# Set here configurations for the database connection

# Connection url for the database "supermarketpro"
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mercatoPro?useSSL=false

# Username and password
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = password

# Keep the connection alive if idle for a long time (needed in production)
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1

# ===============================
# = JPA / HIBERNATE
# ===============================

# Use spring.jpa.properties.* for Hibernate native properties (the prefix is
# stripped before adding them to the entity manager).

# Show or not log for each sql query
spring.jpa.show-sql = true

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, update): with "update" the database
# schema will be automatically updated accordingly to java entities found in
# the project
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

# Naming strategy
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy

# Allows Hibernate to generate SQL optimized for a particular DBMS
#spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

**Logs**

```
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.1.3)

2023-09-23T14:14:34.933+02:00  INFO 45877 --- [  restartedMain] c.mercatoPro.restAPI.RestApiApplication  : Starting RestApiApplication using Java 20.0.2 with PID 45877 (/Users/michy/Downloads/restAPI/target/classes started by michy in /Users/michy/Downloads/restAPI)
2023-09-23T14:14:34.939+02:00  INFO 45877 --- [  restartedMain] c.mercatoPro.restAPI.RestApiApplication  : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-09-23T14:14:35.043+02:00  INFO 45877 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2023-09-23T14:14:35.044+02:00  INFO 45877 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2023-09-23T14:14:36.252+02:00  INFO 45877 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-09-23T14:14:36.308+02:00  INFO 45877 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 46 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-09-23T14:14:37.149+02:00  INFO 45877 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2023-09-23T14:14:37.162+02:00  INFO 45877 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-09-23T14:14:37.162+02:00  INFO 45877 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.12]
2023-09-23T14:14:37.263+02:00  INFO 45877 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-09-23T14:14:37.265+02:00  INFO 45877 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2219 ms
2023-09-23T14:14:37.445+02:00  INFO 45877 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2023-09-23T14:14:37.519+02:00  INFO 45877 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.2.7.Final
2023-09-23T14:14:37.521+02:00  INFO 45877 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000406: Using bytecode reflection optimizer
2023-09-23T14:14:37.701+02:00  INFO 45877 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.b.i.BytecodeProviderInitiator        : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : bytebuddy
2023-09-23T14:14:37.851+02:00  INFO 45877 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.o.j.p.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo      : No LoadTimeWeaver setup: ignoring JPA class transformer
2023-09-23T14:14:37.868+02:00  INFO 45877 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-09-23T14:14:38.115+02:00  INFO 45877 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@5775c599
2023-09-23T14:14:38.117+02:00  INFO 45877 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2023-09-23T14:14:38.385+02:00  INFO 45877 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.b.i.BytecodeProviderInitiator        : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : bytebuddy
2023-09-23T14:14:39.117+02:00  INFO 45877 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
Hibernate: alter table prodotti modify column prezzo  float(23) not null
2023-09-23T14:14:39.206+02:00  INFO 45877 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-09-23T14:14:39.258+02:00  WARN 45877 --- [  restartedMain] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2023-09-23T14:14:39.670+02:00  INFO 45877 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2023-09-23T14:14:39.706+02:00  INFO 45877 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2023-09-23T14:14:39.718+02:00  INFO 45877 --- [  restartedMain] c.mercatoPro.restAPI.RestApiApplication  : Started RestApiApplication in 5.395 seconds (process running for 6.117)
```

[image: Postman GET request at "localhost:8080/prodotti"]

Comment: I'm fixing the question, code snippet is not working properly apparently :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring searches for components: controllers, repos in the `basePackage`. By default, the base package is the package where main Application class is located and which has `@SpringBootApplication` annotation over it. You can specify another base package, if your components are located in the different location. But by default it is better to use same base package.

So as long as other components of your application are located in the same or child packages, you don't need to specify base package via @ComponentScan annotation.

Since you specified base package, different from the one your Controller class is located, Spring did not find and did not register ProdottiController (and other repos), that is why you got 404.

Just remove `@ComponentScan` annotation, and Spring will fall back to the defaults (basePackage = "*main application class package*") and will find the controller.

Note, please, you do not need an additional slash here, just leave `@GetMapping`

```
    // Legge tutti i prodotti
@GetMapping
public java.util.List<Prodotti> getAllProdotti() {
    return servizioProdotti.getAllProdotti();
}
```

Overwise you have to call localhost:8080/prodotti/

Comment: Ok thanks, tried this and it didn't solve my problem, any other idea?

I added a picture to show you my GET request on Postman.

Comment: Please, add 1. logs which get on server side, 2. Application configuration

Comment: Just added the requested info. Thanks for helping :)

Comment: Ok, please, remove application.properties as it contains your personal data - passwords, etc and it is not helping with your issue anyway :), I ment Application class file where you configure spring mvc. 
Your code should work, there should some not obvious error. Could you please check spelling, that all letters are from english alphabit and there is no typo. Also can you access any other endpoint? For example, localhost:8080/prodotti/1 ?

Comment: I removed my password, thanks, I missed it completely :P I did triple check spelling and there was no mistake. I'll recheck though. I can't access any other endpoint, I always get the "Whitelable" page. I'll try and give you the application class, give me a minute.

Comment: Regarding Application class - you are using SpringBoot, so you should have one. Do you have @SpringBootApplication over there? Logs say that 0 repositories found, so it means that packages are not scanned or wrong package is scanned

Comment: Where can I find it? Sorry I'm a bit confused :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255388/discussion-between-sve-kamenska-and-mike).